# Python - Defining fraction

Tags: python, fractions

Using Python define named fraction 
Defining using function without using import and return with format of a/b
Examples

> fraction(9,24)
>       result = > 3/8

I'm not really good at English so I don't really know what fraction really is.
My school only taught in my country's language.

```
def fraction(a,b):
    return a ? b ?
fraction(9,24)
```

Comment: You can read about fractions on the simple english wikipedia: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without fraction modules, call factorise(9,24) will return a_ret as 3 and b_ret as 8.

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

def factorise(a,b):
    a_list = prime_factors(a)
    a1_list = a_list
    b_list = prime_factors(b)
    b1_list = b_list
    for x in a_list:
        if x in b1_list: 
            b1_list.remove(x) 
            a1_list.remove(x)
    for x in b_list:
        if x in a1_list: 
            a1_list.remove(x)
            b1_list.remove(x) 
    a_ret = 1
    b_ret = 1
    for x in a1_list:
        a_ret *= x
    for x in b1_list:
        b_ret *= x
    print(a_ret,b_ret)
```

Comment: I hope it does not output 1/3, but 3/8

Comment: Sorry, I tried (8,24) in local shell

Comment: can you do without using import Fraction?

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A fraction is a number written as `a/b` so the decimal `0.4` equals the fraction `4/10` equals the reduced (simplest) fraction `2/5`.

There are a number of ways to do what you want. The simplest is probably to use the `fractions.Fraction` class (although this may be considered cheating if this is a school exercise):

```
from fractions import Fraction

def fraction(a, b):
    ''' return simplest fraction as a string of the form a/b '''
    fr = Fraction(a, b)
    return '{}/{}'.format(fr.numerator, fr.denominator)
```

Example:

```
fraction(9, 27) # --> '1/3'
```

Comment: I think you know that they are meant to implement the algorithm themselves and not rely upon a library.

Comment: @PeterWood yeah you may be right, but I didn't want to do that because it would defeat the point of the exercise.

Comment: I been figure out all day I wonder if anyone can show me without using from fractions import fraction

Answer (score 2):

Without using the `fractions` module, you can just calculate the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of `a` and `b` and divide both numbers by that to "normalize" the [fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)).

```
def fraction(a, b):
    g = gcd(a, b)
    return "%d / %d" % (a // g, b // g)
```

Example:

```
>>> gcd(9, 24)
3
>>> fraction(9, 24)
'3 / 8'
```

Implementation of `gcd` is left as an excercise to the reader (or use `math.gcd`)

Answer (score 1):

We can find the most reduced form of a fraction by seeing if any number up to a the smallest value divides both - we can then call fraction recursively to handle further iterations:

```py
def fraction( numerator, denominator):
    min_val = min(numerator, denominator)
    # We go from 2 -> min_val here, 
    # skipping 1 because every number is divisible by one and it gets us nowhere
    for divisor in range(2, min_val+1):
        if (numerator % divisor == 0 and denominator % divisor == 0):
            # We know the fraction can be reduced, 
            # because divisor divides both numerator and denominator
            return(fraction(numerator / divisor, denominator / divisor))
    return('{}/{}'.format(numerator, denominator))
```

Test the output:

```
>>> fraction(5, 10)
'1/2'
```

If you have any questions let me know, recursion is a little weird sometimes but it's powerful and makes our life a lot simpler

Comment: already tried on Repl.it and it doesn't work. Is there a lining problem?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 9, in fraction
    return(fraction(numerator / divisor, denominator / divisor))
  File "main.py", line 5, in fraction
    for divisor in range(2, min_val+1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I don't know what that is, it works fine for me on my machine - what is the error? Is it python 3 or python 2?

Comment: its python 3.6.1

Comment: @SHXH_ONTHEMARZ Ah, looks like it's passing floats instead of integers. If they are less than 1 you may have to extend the code I wrote to include scaling the numerator and denominator *up* to integers. Have a go and let me know if you get stuck. That part wasn't clear in your definition

Comment: I change the for divisor in range(2, 100) //or more then it worked

Comment: I don't know if this will break the min_val=min(numerator ,denominator) on line 2

Comment: I can now remove the line 2 and the code still work

Comment: However, for fraction(16,-48) should be -1/3 but it turned out to be 1/-3

Comment: are you still there sir I don't understand can you edit your code?

Comment: This will take rather long if `a` and `b` are both large co-prime numbers. Probably better use Euclid's Algorithm.

Comment: @tobias_k I agree, I was just scared of describing Euclid's algorithm to someone who didn't understand what a fraction

Comment: @mr.yellowmandoes You need to see what kind of inputs the function will get, can it be passed negative numbers? (clearly it can, because you told me that) Can it be passed numbers that are non-integers?